# Recover data from corrupted file

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have a HDF5 file that for some reason got corrupted. I am trying to retrieve the portion of the file that is essentially fine. I can read all datasets from the groups that do not contain a corrupted field just fine. But I cannot read any of the not-corrupted datasets from a group that has also a corrupted dataset.

The funny thing is however that I **can easily read** those datasets using HDFView. I.e. I can open them, and find all numerical values. Using HDFView I can only not read the corrupted dataset.

My question is how can I exploit this, and retrieve as much data as I can?

When reading with h5py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "repair.py", line 44, in <module>
    print(data['/dt_yield/000000'][...])
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 167, in __getitem__
    oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5o.pyx", line 190, in h5py.h5o.open
KeyError: 'Unable to open object (bad heap free list)'
```

When reading with C++:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.1) thread 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 294 in H5Dopen2(): unable to open dataset
    major: Dataset
    minor: Can't open object
  #001: H5Dint.c line 1362 in H5D__open_name(): not found
    major: Dataset
    minor: Object not found
  #002: H5Gloc.c line 428 in H5G_loc_find(): can't find object
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #003: H5Gtraverse.c line 867 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #004: H5Gtraverse.c line 594 in H5G_traverse_real(): can't look up component
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #005: H5Gobj.c line 1156 in H5G__obj_lookup(): can't locate object
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #006: H5Gstab.c line 890 in H5G__stab_lookup(): unable to protect symbol table heap
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Protected metadata error
  #007: H5HL.c line 364 in H5HL_protect(): unable to load heap data block
    major: Heap
    minor: Unable to protect metadata
  #008: H5AC.c line 1763 in H5AC_protect(): H5C_protect() failed
    major: Object cache
    minor: Unable to protect metadata
  #009: H5C.c line 2561 in H5C_protect(): can't load entry
    major: Object cache
    minor: Unable to load metadata into cache
  #010: H5C.c line 6877 in H5C_load_entry(): Can't deserialize image
    major: Object cache
    minor: Unable to load metadata into cache
  #011: H5HLcache.c line 763 in H5HL__cache_datablock_deserialize(): can't initialize free list
    major: Heap
    minor: Unable to initialize object
  #012: H5HLcache.c line 241 in H5HL__fl_deserialize(): bad heap free list
    major: Heap
    minor: Out of range
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type H5::FileIException
```

## Recovery script (using h5py)

This is the implementation I have so far to recover at least everything that h5py can read directly:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py, os, time

def getdatasets(key,archive):

  if key[-1] != '/': key += '/'

  out = []

  for name in archive[key]:

    path = key + name

    if isinstance(archive[path], h5py.Dataset):
      out += [path]
    else:
      try   : out += getdatasets(path,archive)
      except: pass

  return out

data  = h5py.File('data.hdf5' ,'r')
fixed = h5py.File('fixed.hdf5','w')

datasets = getdatasets('/',data)

groups = list(set([i[::-1].split('/',1)[1][::-1] for i in datasets]))
groups = [i for i in groups if len(i)>0]

idx    = np.argsort(np.array([len(i.split('/')) for i in groups]))
groups = [groups[i] for i in idx]

for group in groups:
  fixed.create_group(group)

for path in datasets:

  # - check path
  if path not in data: continue

  # - try reading
  try   : data[path]
  except: continue

  # - get group name
  group = path[::-1].split('/',1)[1][::-1]

  # - minimum group name
  if len(group) == 0: group = '/'

  # - copy data
  data.copy(path, fixed[group])
```

Comment: Maybe it is silly, but you can export data from HDFView (right-click in the dataset> Export). Depending on the amount of dataset it could be tedious, but you have that option.

Comment: @pablo_worker. Thanks, yes that's works. I'm looking for an automated tool though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a neat way to recover all top-level groups which do not contain broken nodes. Can simply be extended to lower level groups by recursive calling.

```
import h5py as h5

def RecoverFile( f1, f2 ):
    """  recover read-open HDF5 file f1 to write-open HDF5 file f2  """
    names = []
    f1.visit(names.append)
    for n in names:
        try:
            f2.create_dataset( n, data=f1[n][()] )
        except:
            pass



with h5.File( file_broken, 'r' ) as fb:
    with h5.File( file_recover, 'w' ) as fr:
        for key in fb.keys():
            try:
                fr.create_dataset( key, data=fb[key][()] )
            except:
                try:
                    fr.create_group(key)
                    RecoverFile( fb[key], fr[key] )
                except:
                    fr.__delitem__(key)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think it might need to generalisation. What if a dataset is stored on the root: what if you have `/a` as dataset? Also, it seems that the `.value` method has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Great! FYI I by now also have a command-line script to do this : https://github.com/tdegeus/GooseHDF5/blob/master/GooseHDF5/cli/G5repair.py